# Delete method giving 500 error, for this endpoint /wc/store/cart/items

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

**woocommerce_rest_cart_error Unable to retrieve cart.**
Delete method giving 500 error, for this endpoint /wc/store/cart/items.

To reproduce

```
jQuery.ajax({
  type: 'delete',
  url: '/wp-json/wc/store/cart/items',
  xhrFields: {
    withCredentials: true
  }
});
```

This endpoint should return an empty array, but it is giving me 500 error.

Comment: I'd guess "Unable to retrieve cart" means you're not sending the right cookies or authentication to the API endpoint. I'm not a WooCommerce expert so I don't know how this should work: can you check the request in your browser's debug tools to make sure this looks like an API request that the existing WooCommerce code makes? Can you see how that makes AJAX requests in the JavaScript?

Comment: I am sending the right cookies. The issue is this API used in the woocommerce-gutenberg-products-block package and that package is for internal use only. So this is not documented.